# Galaxy S10+Device is not compatible with my Application

Tags: android, react-native

I created an application only for mobile device not for tablets so I added compatible-screens code in my application Manifest.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="420"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Everything was working fine, but now when every we try to download application in S10+ I am getting error message **Device is not compatible for this version**

I checked in Device catalogs in play console and there its showing S10+ is Enable for users.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an application that has a version for Tablets and another for Phones.
I filter by the screen size:

- Small and Normal for Phones
- Large and xLarge for Tablets

I have a problem with an user using s10+, the download from the playstore gets the Tablet version of the app.

The problem is S10+ uses Large screen size, so your app won't support it.

I emulated it's size and density on ADB and it shows that it is considered Large:
[image]